# How to upload multiple files on Android using the multiple property?

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, upload, nexus-5

I got a,

`<input type="file" multiple accept="image/*" />`

and I want my android users to be able to upload multiple files at a time.  Users using nexus-5 report being unable to upload multiple files at a time.  I also tried adding capture="camera" to the input but this only auto open the camera and only associate one picture at a time again.  This works everywhere except on Android.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: EtienneT.. Any fix for this ?

Comment: No, sorry, nothing new

Comment: @EtienneT Is there anything now? I have Android 5.1.1 and Chrome 55 and its still not working

Answer (score 9):

I've hit the same brick wall. I've tried a number of mobile browsers and can't find any that work.

I found this link that tells you that none of the Android browsers support this:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-multiple

From extensive searching, I've seen information that suggests that Chromium supports this (but no beta yet) and it should make it into Chrome for Android but no indication of time-frame.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to have changed since my last answer. If you now look at:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-multiple

You'll now see that Chrome 42 (or better) for Android does now support multiple file upload provided you're running Android 5.0 or better. That's quite a limitation but at least it's an improvement. As Android 5 (Lollipop) gains market share (18.1% in August 2015) this become more practical.

Comment: I have chrome 47 and android 5 and it still isn't letting me choose more than one img to upload

Comment: Android 4.4.4 with Chrome 49 - multiple file selection work fine

Comment: @AlexanderPravdin can you give more details on how exactly you got it to work? I have Android 5.0.2 and Chrome 49 and it is not working.
Here is a test page: https://jsfiddle.net/67j6177d/

Comment: Just this html code: `<input type="file" name="attachment[]" multiple="multiple"/>` and it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one trick. Hit your normal `<input type='file' multiple>` button. File picker appears: do a long press on a file to select it, then select other files.
On the top bar an "Open" appears, select it and then multiple files are added to the files collection.
Kudos to Simon@atp for this.

However, not all available file pickers may work.

Answer (score 2):

As of 12/20/2017, the new Chrome browser is allowing multiple file selection. Just select your files and click "Open" in the upper right hand corner.

Answer (score 0):

You could work around this limitation by using javascript, canvas and blobs.

See https://github.com/josefrichter/resize/blob/master/public/preprocess.js for some example code to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. And I tested the latest chrome and FireFox, both not working.

But the QQ browser which is using X5 core is seems to be the only browser works as I expected. So My solution would be using a App shell to encapsulate the X5 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from [Median.co](https://median.co) (formerly GoNative.io). As per our requirement we have to check and enter our URL. And they will send Android code link and DEMO apk over mail. In this file using we can upload multiple files in our web view. If we have to publish the app we have  to purchase that thing. I tried to understand the multi file upload code. But couldn't find any thing help full. If any one crack that thing please tell us.