# Cloudinary\Error: Missing required parameter - file

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, cloudinary

I am using cloudinary to upload images on my Laravel application. When I try to upload images using my mobile device, I get this error:-

> Cloudinary\Error:  Missing required parameter - file

When I try uploading from my laptop, it works well. This is my code:

```
$photos = $request->file;
if(isset($request->file)){

    foreach ($photos as $photo){

        $file = $photo;
        Cloudder::upload($file->getPathname());
        $response = Cloudder::getResult();
        $path = $response['secure_url'];
        $publicId = Cloudder::getPublicId();
        $file_size = $file->getClientSize();
        //create record
    }
}
```

Please what might be the problem?

Comment: Please share the frontend code. Where the file input located.

Comment: <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple class="file-upload-default" required>

Comment: Using any plugin to upload file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Basic multiple file upload not working on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47010949/basic-multiple-file-upload-not-working-on-mobile)

Comment: @VikashPathak how is this a duplicate? Or you just trying to be funny????

Comment: it's not issue at Laravel end....it's from frontend, your file not getting attached from mobile device. And liked issue is solution for same problem.

Comment: Once you will able to attach the file, Laravel will process that.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the $file is empty? Can you please check this?

Comment: It can't be. I made it compulsory. 

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'name' => 'required',
                'description' => 'required',
                'file' => 'required'
            ],[
                'file.required' => 'Please add Photo(s) for this Product'
            ]);

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
if(isset($request->hasFile(file))){

foreach ($request->file('file') as $photo){

    $file = $photo;
    Cloudder::upload($file->getPathname());
    $response = Cloudder::getResult();
    $path = $response['secure_url'];
    $publicId = Cloudder::getPublicId();
    $file_size = $file->getClientSize();
    //create record
} }
```